# Como puedo borrar un los datos de un vector?

Tags: java

Buenos dias tengo este problema y es que tengo guardado en vectores datos de isb, titulo, precio, cantidadDisponible, cantidadVendida y se me pide que al ingresar la posicion del libro se borren los datos o se retiren pero aqui ya no se como hacerlo ayuda porfavor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
este es mi codigo simplificado


//Atributos de la clase
private Scanner sc;
private Libro[] libros = new Libro[3];


public String consultarTodosLosLibros() {
    String resultado = "";
    resultado += "\nLibros:";
    for (int i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {
        resultado += "\n" + (i + 1) + ". ";
        if (libros[i] == null) {
            resultado += "Espacio disponible.";
        } else {
            resultado += libros[i];
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}


  public void retirarLibro() {
    System.out.println(consultarTodosLosLibros());
    System.out.println("Ingrese el número de libro que desea retirar:");
    int posicionLibro = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) -1 ;
     if (posicionLibro>=0 &&  posicionLibro<libros.length) {
        //falta aqui
        //libros[posicionLibro] == null; ?revisar
        
         
         System.out.println("Se retiró el libro " + (posicionLibro+1) + ":");
         System.out.println(consultarTodosLosLibros());
     } else {
         System.out.println("No se puede retirar el libro porque no existe.");
     }         
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaría agregar la condición `libros[posicionLibro] != null` y en el cuerpo de la condición `libros[posicionLibro] = null;` para remover el libro.

```
public void retirarLibro() {
        System.out.println(consultarTodosLosLibros());
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de libro que desea retirar:");
        int posicionLibro = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) -1 ;
         if (
                  posicionLibro >= 0 
                    &&  posicionLibro < libros.length 
                    && libros[posicionLibro] != null // condición nueva
          ) {
           
            
             libros[posicionLibro] = null; // retirar libro
             
             System.out.println("Se retiró el libro " + (posicionLibro+1) + ":");
             System.out.println(consultarTodosLosLibros());
    
         } else {
             System.out.println("No se puede retirar el libro porque no existe.");
     }
```

Comment: libros[posicionLibro] == null; pero al hacer esto esta mal falta revisar esto como hago

Comment: no le pongas `==` porque estas comparando que sea igual, usa solo `=`\ para asignar

Comment: ohhh gracias ya pude, crack